# Getting variable from asp/aspx to workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, aspx, edit-form

I need to move a variable saved on a SP list item(LIST A) to a workflow that starts on the creation of a new item in a different list(LIST B). This new item on LIST B will be created upon pressing an .aspx button in a web part on LIST A's edit item form. 
When clicked, this button will call a C# method taking a value (call it School_ID) from the item on LIST A. C# code will then create a new item on LIST B and fill it with the value retrieved from LIST A. the School_ID.

This workflow can then, using the school_ID value retrieve further information from the item on LIST A which it now has a (unique) Identifier as a reference.

My question is, Is this at all viable. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can retrieve the value from list A by using a HttpSend activity in your workflow. I only tried this for an app I created in Visual Studio, but the logic probably is the same for SPD as well. Steps I took:

1. Get the site Url with the LookupWorkflowContextProperty activity --> gives xSiteUrl (probably you can omit this step, but it's necessary in my App)
2. Get the Id of the item from List A that contains the data you want
   to lookup --> gives xId
3. Add the HttpSend activity to your workflow with the following properties method=GET, Uri=xSiteUrl + "_api/web/Lists/getByTitle("List A")/items(" + xId + ")", ResponseContent=xDynamicValueVariable
4. Add a GetDynamicValueProperties activity to your workflow and set source=d/FieldName (name of Field you want to lookup the value for) and Assign To appropriate variable you created.

Comment: Can you possible extend this answer with details of how to use this activity? It would make your answer very helpful

Comment: edited my post :)